# Can somebody explain below code related to StringBuffer in java?

Tags: java, increment, stringbuffer

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("A");
```

Now to increment the letter A I have written below code-

```
if (sb.charAt(0)=='A') {
    sb.setCharAt(0, 'B');
} else {
    sb.setCharAt(0, 'C');
}
```

But somewhere I read that this can be done with below code as well (and it worked!)

```
sb.setCharAt(0, (char)(sb.charAt(0) + 1));
```

Can somebody explain the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `char + int` `char` is interpreted as `int` which represents index of used char in Unicode Table.

So when you execute `sb.charAt(0) + 1` it is same as `'A' + 1` and is evaluated as `65 + 1` which equals `66` (and [character indexed with that value](http://unicode-table.com/en/0042/) in Unicode Table is `B`).

Now since `setCharAt` expects as second argument `char` you must *(cast)* that `int` to `char` which gives you back `'B'` and `sb.setCharAt(0, ..)` simply sets up that character at position `0` of in your StringBuffer.

Comment: you were faster, cheers mate... I've typed too slowly goddamit :)

Comment: @Pshemo, Thanks a lot ! Now I have understood the logic behind increment.

Answer (score 0):

If the first character is an `A` change the first character to a `B`. Otherwise, set the first character to a `C`. Your modified version

```
sb.setCharAt(0, (char) (sb.charAt(0) + 1));
```

would only work *the same way* for input of `A` and `B` respectively (because it increments the first character in the `StringBuffer`).

Comment: So here 'sb.charAt(0)+1' actually increments character at index 0?

Comment: @AjayLamba Yes. `'A' + 1` is `'B'`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch To be more precise `'A' + 1` is `66`, otherwise we wouldn't need casting here.

Comment: @Pshemo True. `(char) ('A' + 1)` is `'B'`.

Answer (score 0):

`sb.charAt(0)` is going to retrieve the first character. So `sb.charAt(0) + 1` will add 1 to the first character (turning an A into a B, a B into a C, etc.). So, lets suppose the first character is an A. Then  `sb.charAt(0) + 1 == 'B'` so your method is `sb.setCharAt(0, 'B')`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works because of the implicit conversion. As you probably know, every character has it's [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) number representation. For example, letter 'A' is number 64. When you write

```
sb.setCharAt(0, (char) (sb.charAt(0) + 1));
```

It automatically converts (implicitly) the character to integer because it needs to add 1 to it. So your result becomes `64+1 = 65.` After this, you **explicitly** call a typecast operator `(char)` to convert the integer number of 65 to char it represents, and it's B.